# Elasticsearch intersecting polygon with points

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, spatial-query

I have elasticsearch v7.4 running and I need to find features that intersects bunch of points.

When I'm using 'Point' and put one coordinate pair it's running ok.

```
GET xxxxx/_search
{

  "query": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "geometry": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": 
                  [-90, 40]
            },
            "relation": "intersects"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But when I'm trying to change 'Point' to 'MultiPoint' I receive an error

> Field [geometry] does not support multipoint queries

```
GET xxxx/_search
{

  "query": {
        "geo_shape": {
          "geometry": {
            "shape": {
              "type": "MultiPoint",
              "coordinates": [
                  [-90, 40],
                  [-80, 30]
                ]  
            },
            "relation": "intersects"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Is this something related to v7.4 or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [issue #27954](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/27954#issuecomment-452105862), BKD-tree backed geoshapes did not support MultiPoint queries, but it is supported as of [7.7](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/52133) (see [7.7 release notes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/release-notes-7.7.0.html#feature-7.7.0))

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me feedback on, if this multipoint approach would work in newer version. I mean is the syntax correct...

Comment: I confirm, the query does not error out on 7.17